# Having trouble grabbing data from an array with the array.map method in React on an item that is clearly an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, function, object

I am building a cryptocurrency app project for my portfolio using react. Everything is good, except that I am running into issues trying to map over items using the map method on an array. I have hardcoded the mockup data into my state object:

```
  const targetObj = pairs.markets.filter(obj => obj.quoteAsset === selectedCurrencyState.selectedBaseCurrency);
  const filteredObject = targetObj[0];
  console.log(filteredObj);
```

[image]

As you can see, when I console log the obj, it shows that baseAssets should be an array. But when I perform

```
console.log(filteredObj.baseAssets.map(item => item.baseAsset));
```

I get

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'baseAssets')

. In addition, for some reason when I try to access the quoteAsset, that should be accessible by dot notation,

it gives me console.log(filteredObj.quoteAsset);

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'quoteAsset')

Comment: First render, things aren't there yet. Post more code that shows state and all that and we can recommend where to check for that sort of issue but generally speaking always assume it might not be populated initially.

Comment: Also, state/render is basically a cycle. It's async and sometimes batched. Console log might be misleading for some things.

Comment: As I can see in the 1st image you are using console on filteredobj but your variable name just above it filteredObject. Or dou have another variable of filteredobj.please confirm it.

Comment: I think it's easy to see this isn't reproducible with just these 4 lines of code. The first two lines don't even include the `filteredObj` variable. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: sorry, it was the same object. I was doing some further testing the whole time I was writing this post so the naming switched. Will edit it. Thanks guys